# How can I get distribution density and distribution function on the same axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have dictionarу data_for_chart: keys - value of x axis; values - value of y axis.
I need to repeat chart like this:
[image]
I do:

```
x_values = list(data_for_chart[index_data]['values'].keys())
y_values = list(data_for_chart[index_data]['values'].values())
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.subplots()
ax.plot(x_values, y_values, ':o', linewidth=2)
df = pd.DataFrame(y_values, index=x_values)
df.plot(kind='density', ax=ax, bw_method=3, secondary_y=True, label='Density function dQ3 ()d, %')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.grid(axis='x')
ax.legend()
ax.set_ylabel('%')
ax.set_xlabel('mkm')
buf = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format="png")
```

And I get:
[image]
Distribution function the same, but distribution density is not correct. How can I get correct distribution density?

Comment: What's wrong about the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get derivative:

```
derivative = {}
for i in range(0, len(x_values)-1):
    if i == 0:
        derivative[x_values[i]] = y_values[i]
    derivative[x_values[i]] = y_values[i+1] - y_values[i]
x_values_derivative = list(data_for_chart[index_data]['derivative'].keys())
y_values_derivative = list(data_for_chart[index_data]['derivative'].values())
```

get distribution density

```
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.bar(x_values_derivative, y_values_derivative, color='green', linewidth=2, label='distribution density')
ax1.set_ylabel('%'))
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.55, 0, 0, 0.8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code and outcome you provided, the data in your `y_values` variable doesn't support the kind of plot you're after. The blue line where you plot `x_values` versus `y_values` shows that this data represents a cumulative distribution. It would be best if you could actually calculate a histogram from your original data, and then calculate the cumulative sum of that histogram. If that's not possible, here is an example that should help you get close to the chart you're after:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Make a test cumulative distribution
test_data = np.random.normal(size=200)
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(test_data, bins=50)
bin_width = bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0]

## e'll pretend this is your data
x_values = [i + bin_width/2 for i in bin_edges[:-1]]
y_values = hist.cumsum()

## Back out a histogram from the cumulative distribution
hist_calc = np.diff(y_values, prepend=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.bar(x_values, hist_calc, edgecolor="black", color="lightblue", width=bin_width)
ax2.plot(x_values, y_values, color="red")
plt.show()
```

[image]